# The probability of two or more hurricanes making contact with the ground in the United States is 0.28. Find the rate of Poisson process.

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, simulation

The occurrences of hurricanes that make landfall during the meteorological phenomenon
“El Niño” are modeled as a Poisson process (Bove et al. (1998)). The authors
claim that "During an El Niño year, the probability of two or more hurricanes
making contact with the ground in the United States is 0.28 ”. Find the rate of
Poisson process.

My approach:

Let the beginning of "El Niño" be $N_0=0$ and $N_1$ the end.

We know that $$P(N_1-N_0\geq 2) = 0.28$$

Now let's find $\lambda$ $$P(N_1-N_0\geq 2) = P(N_1 \geq 2)=1- P(N_1 < 2)= 1-2e^{-\lambda}(\lambda) $$

Then $$1-2e^{-\lambda}(\lambda)=0.28$$

Then $$\lambda=0.2738$$

I'm not sure if my approach is correct. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: No - $\lambda=0.2738$ is not correct.  Your major error is in $1-2e^{-\lambda}(\lambda)$ which should have been $1 - (1+\lambda)e^{-\lambda}$.  Your other error was in solving that for $\lambda$